# Quick question on Set Union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A= \{p,q,r \}$ and $B= \{x,y,z \}$.

Now I studied basic 1st order logic and I'm just now getting into set theory. 
So when I hear that the union relation is a statement about the elements that are in either $A$ or $B$, is the union $A\cup B$ necessarily $ \{p,q,r,x,y,z \}$ or can it be just $\{p,q,r\}$ (or just $ \{x,y,z\}$)?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a new set, $C=A\cup B$, and $C$ contains all elements the from $A$ and all the elements from $B$. So $C=\{p,q,r,x,y,z\}.$  So, basically, you can think of the union of any number of sets as a new set which contains every element of each set of the union.

Answer (score 0):

From a first-order logic perspective, you can define the union using quantifiers, connectives, and the set-membership ($\in$) relation.

$$x \in A \cup B \iff ((x \in A) \vee (x \in B)).$$

Now from logic you can immediately see that it's $\{p, q, r, x, y, z\}$.